# Capture result of HTML5 FileReader when using promises in async

Tags: angular, html, typescript, es6-promise, photoeditorsdk

I have an Angular 4 application where I am reading an image & trying to pass the base64 string to another variable - however I am having an issue due to the async nature of this - the `image.src` is empty and therefore the value has passed correctly to the image object?

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let image = new Image();
    var promise = this.getBase64(fileObject, this.processImage());
    promise.then(function(base64) {
        console.log(base64);    // outputs string e.g 'data:image/jpeg;base64,........'
    });

    image.src = base64; // how to get base64 string into image.src var here??

    let editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI({
        container: this.editor.nativeElement
        editor: {
           image: image
        }
    });
}

/**
 * get base64 string from supplied file object
 */
public getBase64(file, onLoadCallback) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() { resolve(reader.result); };
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}

public processImage() {

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just put `let image = new Image();` and `image.src = base64;` inside the promise callback function?

Comment: Move it to `promise.then` or use async await? What's the problem on +400???

Comment: So you want to use promise but don't want to wait for that to be fulfilled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the code is **asynchronous** in nature, you will have to wait for the result if you want to use it. In your case, you will have to **wait until your promise is resolved**. So your code should look like:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   let image = new Image();
   var promise = this.getBase64(this.fileObject, this.processImage);
   promise.then(function(base64: string) {
       console.log(base64);    
       image.src = base64;

       let editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI({
           container: this.editor.nativeElement
           editor: {
             image: image
           }
       });
   });
}
```

I have changed following things:

1. I moved code for `ReactUI` instantiation inside promise callback
2. Specified type of `base64` parameter as `string`
3. Fixed typo in `getBase64` function call, from `this.processImage()` to `this.processImage` so it is passing callback function and not result of `processImage` function.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

Since `getBase64` is an async operation you can't use it's result right away. You need to wait for it either by calling `then` (as you have already experimented with) or using `async/await`.

The `async/await` version (which is also part of the es 2017 standard) is simpler to understand especially if you are new to async programming. A general rule of thumb, if you see a `Promise` and need to use the value you will need to use the `await` operator (and make your method async)

```
async ngAfterViewInit() {
    let image = new Image();
    var base64 = await this.getBase64(fileObject, this.processImage());

    image.src = base64; //Now available

    let editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI({
        container: this.editor.nativeElement
        editor: {
           image: image
        }
    });
}
public getBase64(file, onLoadCallback) {
    return new Promise<string>(function(resolve, reject) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() { resolve(reader.result as string); };
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
```

You can also move your code to the callback passed to a `then` call, but this may be a bit harder to read (especially if you are just starting out with async code) and if you have to orchestrate multiple async operations reading the code quickly becomes an issue

```
async ngAfterViewInit() {
    let image = new Image();
    this.getBase64(fileObject, this.processImage())
        .then(base64=>
        {
            image.src = base64; // available now 

            let editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI({
                container: this.editor.nativeElement
                editor: { image }
            });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`promise.then` is an async function which means the code comes after this statement will be executed first and then callback function within `then` will be executed. So, you should move your code into callback of `then`.

```
promise.then((base64: string) => {
    console.log(base64);    // outputs string e.g 'data:image/jpeg;base64,........'
    console.log(typeof base64); // type is string
    image.src = base64;

    let editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.ReactUI({
        container: this.editor.nativeElement
        editor: {
           image: image
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit:** I changed the callback function to fat arrow function `() => {}`, it's because you are accessing one of the component fields by `this.editor`, and `function`s have their own scope. You may get an error saying `cannot read nativeElement of undefined`.

Comment: Seems to work however I am getting a `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'` even though am certain that the base64 variable is a string. I have also declared the image as any e.g `public image: any` - any reason why I am getting typescript error within my editor? (although it seems to run...)

Comment: You can define `base64` explicitly string since you know it’ll be a string during runtime. So try `function(base64: string)`